# asp.net mvc jquery filling image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i want to refill the image when i click on the capthca . how can i do that?

```
 public ActionResult Image()
    {
        var builder = new XCaptcha.ImageBuilder();
        var result = builder.Create();
        Session.Add("Cap", result.Solution);
        return new FileContentResult(result.Image, result.ContentType);
    }


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#images').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/en/form/Image",
            success: function (mydata) {
                $("#images").attr("src", mydata);
            },
            type: "POST"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```
   <input type="image" id="images" src="<%= Url.Action("Image", "ContactForms") %>"
                        alt="Click to refresh" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" size="5" tabindex="1000" dir="ltr" maxlength="5" name="Captcha" id="Captcha" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#images').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', function() {
        // the datetime portion appended to the url avoids caching issues
        // and ensures that a fresh image will be loaded every time
        var d = new Date();
        return this.src + '?' + d.getTime();
    });

    // Remark: not sure about the return false here. This will cancel the 
    // default action of the image button => might not be what you need => 
    // adapt to your requirements
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try just setting the src attribute to the url of the dynamic image url

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#images').click(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "/en/form/Image");
        return false;
    });
});
```